# Dispatch/forward to a servlet that serves static content from a different bundle

Tags: tomcat, spring-mvc, osgi, equinox, spring-dm

As a developer completely new to Spring and OSGi, and returning to Tomcat after a long time, I don't even know if I can ask this question properly. But I hope someone will be able to understand where I am stuck and how I should proceed.

The setup includes a Tomcat 7 bundles in the Equinox OSGi container. A bundle provides the "`MainDispatcherServlet`", which extends `org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet`. Other service bundles register `org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.Controller` instances in the OSGi whiteboard which the `MainDispatcherServlet` listens for. `MainDispatcherServlet` provides an API to map url-patterns to the registered Controllers, which it in turn uses a `SimpleUrlHandlerMapping` to identify the handler for individual requests. The service bundles often implement a javax `GenericServlet`, and wrap it in `ServletWrappingController` for the registration.

This much works smoothly. Now I need the following

**Static Resources**

Dispatch to static resources like images and jsps (don't know if they are considered static) in these bundles.

Searching on SO it seems this can be done with some `<mvc:resources>` magic in the client bundle, even though I don't quite figure out the exact xml. But if I understand right the request would not go through the `MainDispatcherServlet`, which is a requirement.

So the approach I am taking right now is to use a `org.apache.catalina.servlets.DefaultServlet` and wrap it in a Controller as described above. Is this a good way to accomplish this? The problem here is that `DefaultServlet` needs a `ServletContext` and I don't have one to give it.

Is there easy way a to *create* a `ServletContext` that I can inject into the Controller?

**Forward to Static Resources**

Further, I need another `Servlet` in the same client bundle to be able to `forward` to the jsps in the bundle using `RequestDispatcher`, an additional reason I need a full fledged `ServletContext`.

In summary, is workable (even if not elegant)? And if so how do I create a ServletConteext? If this is not workable what is the alternative?

All this is quite daunting. Though I am not (cannot :)) ask for implemented prototype, I will appreciate more then a terse instruction like "inject X in Y and wrap it with a Z and you are all set".

Comment: Maybe this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/3819553/283426

Answer (score 0):

The Amdatu open source project has a bundle that allows you to easily serve static resources from a bundle. It uses an extender pattern, which means that you just need to add some information to your bundle's manifest:

```
X-Web-Resource-Version: 1.0
X-Web-Resource: path/to/resources
```

Go to this page [1] and scroll down for more information about it. Of course you need to deploy Amdatu's "resource handler" bundle and its dependencies, which can be found in this repository [2].

[1] http://amdatu.org/components/web.html

[2] http://repository.amdatu.org/snapshot/org.amdatu.web.resourcehandler/org.amdatu.web.resourcehandler-1.0.2.jar